# Is there any book on the numbered notation system?

Tags: notation, learning, numbered-notation

I am interested in the numbered notation system (a.k.a. jiǎnpǔ), and I would like to know if there was any book in order to learn about the details of it (fingering, for example). I already read the Wikipedia page but most of its information is not sourced.

I am not asking about personal opinion about which work is the best/clearest/etc. but simply about the existence of a reference work.

I don't know Chinese, but I can deal with most European languages.

Comment: Hi Joth. Welcome to the site. Just know, we don't address this type of question — requesting resources outside the site itself. There are several questions on this site [dealing with numbered notation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/numbered-notation) which might provide some insight.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the rule because my question is in fact “specific and answerable on this site”

Comment: The guiding language is in the "close reasons" dialog when voting to close a question: "Questions seeking recommendations for specific equipment are off-topic, because they are primarily opinion based. Instead, describe the required function and setting in which the equipment will be used, and ask what you should look for to achieve that." Just know, unless a moderator closes your question, it takes five votes, so others may disagree with me. You could also try reframing your question to be a specific numbered notation issue, in which case we may be able to answer it.

Comment: books and internet resources are considered "equipment" for the purposes of this site.

Comment: I'm with @PiedPiper here: the numbering seems a replacement for note representation. Details like fingering are not covered by these numbers and have to be added using whatever convention seems useful. As in standard notation I expect a strong dependency on the instrument, even the numbering of fingers is not universal.

Comment: @guidot Having read the article more closely, it seems there *are* actually fingering symbols, but they're not explained there.